# Stream is closed error by closing connection

Tags: java, io, stream, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am using this function -

```
public BufferedReader GetResponse(String url, String urlParameters){
    HttpsURLConnection con=null;
    try{
        URL obj = new URL(url);
         con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader returnValue= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        con.disconnect();
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("--------------------There is an error in response function ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("There is an arror in AjaxCAll function of login controller."+e.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("There is an arror in AjaxCAll function of login controller.");
        return null;
    }
    finally{

    }
}
```

If I am using this -

```
con.disconnect();
```

Then I am getting **java.io.IOException: stream is closed error**, 
But if I comment the con.disconnect() line then everything is working fine. I don't know why this is happening.

Calling function

```
BufferedReader rd = utilities.GetResponse(url, urlParameters);
// Send post request
String line = "";
try{
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {   //getting error here if i close connection in response method
        // Parse our JSON response
        responsString += line;
        JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) j.parse(line);
        if (o.containsKey("response")) {
            restMessage = (Map) o.get("response");
        } else {
            restMessage = (Map) o;
        }
    }
} finally{
    rd.close();
}
```

Comment: I also tried by closing connection in finally block, But not working, Same thing happening.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150200/closing-urlconnection-and-inputstream-correctly

This link should help.

Comment: @Sarah I all-ready tried by closing in finally, But not working. Please read my first comment.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of where you are calling this `GetResponse()` method from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JavaDoc of `HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (which HttpsURLConnection extends):

> Calling the disconnect() method may close the underlying socket if a persistent connection is otherwise idle at that time.

Inside your `GetResponse()` method, you got a reference to the `HttpsURLConnection`'s `InputStream` as a `BufferedReader`.  However, when you used `con.disconnect()`, you closed that underlying `InputStream`.

In the code that calls the `GetResponse()` method, you when you later try to use the returned `BufferedReader`, you get an the `java.io.IOException: stream is closed error` because you have already indirectly closed that stream with `con.disconnect()`.

You need to rearrange your code to not call `con.disconnect()` until you are finished with your `BufferedReader`.

This is one approach:

GetResponse():

```
public HttpsURLConnection GetResponse(String url, String urlParameters) {
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    DataOutputStream wr = null;
    try{
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { //better to catch more specific than Exception
        System.out.println("--------------------There is an error in response function ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("There is an arror in AjaxCAll function of login controller."+e.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("There is an arror in AjaxCAll function of login controller.");
        return null;
    }
    finally{
        if(wr != null) {
            wr.close();
        }
    }
    return con;
}
```

Calling code:

```
HttpsURLConnection con = utilities.GetResponse(url, urlParameters);
if(con == null) {
//stop processing or maybe throw an exception depending on what you want to do.
}
BufferedReader rd = null;

// Send post request
String line = "";
try{
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();  //what's this for? nothing is being done with the variable
    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Parse our JSON response
        responsString += line;
        JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) j.parse(line);
        if (o.containsKey("response")) {
            restMessage = (Map) o.get("response");
        }
        else {
            restMessage = (Map) o;
        }
    }
} 
catch(Exception e) { //better to catch more specific than Exception
    //handle exception
}
finally {
    if(rd != null) {
        rd.close();
    }
    con.disconnect(); //we already checked if null above
}
```

Comment: In this [OpenJDK source code link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.disconnect%28%29), `disconnect()` does indeed close the `InputStream`.  That does not necessarily mean that Oracle's JDK code is exactly the same (I couldn't find Oracle source code for `HttpsURLConnection`), but I would expect the behavior is very much the same in order to satisfy the interface as described in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).