# how to close url connection

Tags: java, network-programming

How to close http url connection, when ever am hitting one url to any server, for suppose google, if google dsnt give response, my connection will be opened. so if I try for second and third time, and even after that if google doesn't give response my second and third connections are still in open state.

Now I want to close the connection, before trying for second time and in the same way, if am trying for third time second connection should close.

Any one please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ideally you should invoke .close() in the finally block to release the connection, could you please share your code for better understanding

Comment: See connection timeout

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150200/closing-urlconnection-and-inputstream-correctly) give you some answers?

Comment: Did you call `inputStream.close();` and `httpURLConnection.diconnect()` in a finally block ?