# Java HTTP connection seems to remain open

Tags: java, http

I have created a connection in Java to private API

```
String urlRequest = "https://localhost:8080/orders/create";
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
String certificatePass = "test";
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

URL url = new URL(urlRequest);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new   String(authEncBytes));
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
is.close();
```

After the initial pass, connection seems to remain open, because when running the code from the start, `HttpURLConnection` throws an Exception at **conn.setRequestMethod("POST");**,

> "Can't reset method: already connected"

I managed to somehow close it now, I don't know what have I done, but does anyone know what the issue here could have been? I restarted my PC in the meantime, and it would still thrown an exception at **conn.setRequestMethod("POST");**, I don't understand how can a connection persist between restarts. I also tried adding **conn.disconnect()** before trying to set request method, and that didn't seem to work either. The only thing that made a difference was changing the URL, but I could only connect once, every next time running the code would give me the same exception.

How do I close the connection properly?

Comment: does it happens in debug mode or running ?

Comment: I didn't try running, it was only in debug.

Comment: because it only happens on debug mode and not in running mode, though the reason is unknown. you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766327/android-java-net-protocolexception-connection-already-established/28485029#28485029

Comment: Could have been it, but I just tried adding a breakpoint there again, and it doesn't seem to happen, so no idea.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to reproduce the issue but it seems it only happens at some random times while debugging

Comment: Possible. Annoying though, I've just spent several hours trying to debug it. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome, If you find any answer please post it here. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the issue again today and the problem was with expressions in debug mode. I was calling connect there, I guess while testing so in case anyone didn't know, expressions do affect your variables and can change what's in memory. For instance, having:

```
int a = 5;
System.out.println(a);
```

in your code and having `a = 6` in your Expressions list, `System.out.println(a)` will print 6, not 5.

Deleting expressions fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question already has an answer here.

[Closing URLConnection and InputStream correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150200/closing-urlconnection-and-inputstream-correctly)

Close your connection at end of the code and don't do it before setRequest method.

Comment: The thing is I didn't even establish a connection in the first place because I have yet to add a client certificate, so I'm not getting past the handshake. I never called connection.connect() either.

Comment: You no need to call connect() because you are using getInputStream()
Check this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html

Comment: Thanks, input stream may have been the issue.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer was correct just tick it to help others.